How to detect which voice channel the user joined?
I want my bot to send a message tagging the user and the voice channel when somebody joins a voice channel. My code works, except that no matter which voice channel I join it will always mention "Lobby" in the chat. I want the event to detect the voice channel the user joined.
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if not before.channel and after.channel:
        channel = nextcord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="general")
        voice_channel = nextcord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="Lobby")
        await channel.send(f'I noticed that {member.mention} just joined {voice_channel.mention}!')


I fixed my issue and it was quite simple:
I just noticed i could use mention on after.channel
so specifying voice_channel wasn't needed:
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if not before.channel and after.channel:
        channel = nextcord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="general")
        await channel.send(f'I noticed that {member.mention} just joined {after.channel.mention}!')

